# Laravel get timestamps from database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I can't seem to get the `create_at` timstamp from a eloquent model but this seems not to be the case for other columns e.g. `id`. Can someone help me with this problem?

Data tabel

[image]

The code

```
//getting the collection
$collection = Scan::findOneById($scan->id);

//getting the first object(There is only one)
$storedScan = $collection->first();

//Util to get the type and prints it to console
Utils::printType($storedScan->id);
Utils::printType($storedScan->create_at);
```

Output

```
Type: integer

Type: NULL
```

Comment: Change `Utils::printType($storedScan->create_id);
` to `Utils::printType($storedScan->create_at);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the database column is called create**d**_at

Comment: I just saw it, well that was a fail. Still voted up for you.